# Is there an appropriate SE site for soliciting things like testing webpages on different devices?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am making a video player and have very limited access to mobile devices for testing functionality. I would like to be able to post a link and ask people to test on particular devices and upload screenshots.

Is there an appropriate Stack Exchange site to do this on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I am aware nowhere on the Stack Exchange Network. Your best bet is a forum or maybe some of your colleagues/friends/family. Alternative there might be some online sources available via Google.

[This](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=google+test+mobile+webpages+online&oq=google+test+mobile+webpages+online&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3j64.5720&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=test+mobile+webpages+online&oq=test+mobile+webpages+online&gs_l=serp.3...2066.2066.0.2419.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.laWNzcmHVME&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.d2k&fp=220a12f3b38e9c9e&biw=1215&bih=1319) quick google brought up the following top 2 references:

- [8 popular online apps to test your mobile views](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/10/8-popular-online-apps-to-test-the-mobile-version-of-your-site/)
- [10 Excellent tools for testing your site on Mobile Devices](http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-testing-your-site-on-mobile-devices/)

Comment: As I suspected, but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

No. The Stack Exchange concept of Questions and Answers centers around archive quality -- the ability of content to stand the test of time and be relevant to the next visitor. Feedback on your current projects would quickly be out-dated. Mobile device renderings of your site aren't something that would end up in an encyclopedia, so they don't belong on Stack Exchange.

SE doesn't try to be a place for all the worlds questions, much less all the things they just generally want or need. It's a niche thing.

You can find a full list of [sites in the SE network here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). You may sort by category, then for any of them that interest you I suggest reading the `/about` and `/faq` pages for each as they will have specific details about what is and is not in scope for each site.